# Elastic search, no mappings with filters

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, elasticsearch

In my project we have a feature that creates dynamic fields to the object
so the field type can be for example text, float, object.
and the user can change type for example I have a number field so the mapping in elastic will be float, and I changed the value to text it will cause an error in mapping.

or for example it was object then string, long story short mapping will cause issues, and if I ignored the mappings I will lose the ability to filter on these fields.

Is there a way in elastic that I can ignore the mapping and use filter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch doesn't support change in type of fields. It is really important to define your Schema carefully, it is still possible to change the field type but you would need to `reindex` your data again. For more information about `Reindex API` you can check the ES official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html).

You can also try to implement your field mapping with suffix so each type of your field would have its own field. For example if you have a field name `User` and your client specified it as `long` you can store it as `user_long` and map it as `long` and if the client change the type later on in the application to `string` you can create new field `user_text` and map it as a text. Keep in mind with this approach you might need to convert your data but you won't need `reindexing`.