# How to update/change the existing field type in a mapping of an index in elasticsearch using python?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to update a field type in my existing index mappings but getting BadRequestError using put_mapping method.
The same method works to add a new field but not to update an existing one.
Is there any other method available for the same?

In the below example, i am trying to change the date format of start_time

```py
es_client.indices.put_mapping(index='test-index',properties=properties)
```

This is the error i got

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(meta.status, ApiError)(
```

elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Mapper for [start_time] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [format] from [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||epoch_millis] to [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]')

Comment: I don't think ES allows that ...

Comment: it is not recomndate to update existing field mapping. You can copy data to temp index and then delete current index then create new index and then restore data from temp index.

Comment: You can check my answer to the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457255/elastic-search-no-mappings-with-filters

Comment: As said above you can't. You have to create a new index with the new mapping and then copy old data with [reindex api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it has been mentioned above in the comments, you cannot change a mapping once the index has been created

you need to delete the index, then recreate it with the correct setting